# Changing the text value of a button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a problem with my toggle. I have found similar posts but none that I truly understood.

I want the button to change text to "Project Info -" when clicked and when clicked again revert back to "Project Info +"

Here's the problem (the project info button) -> http://marcuspedersen.com/oyafestivalen.html

The code:

**jquery**

```
$('#toggle').click(function() {
    $('#workinfo').slideToggle (300, 'linear'); 
});
```

**The button**

```
<input type="button" id="toggle" value="Project Info +"/>
```

Answer (score 4):

I'd suggest:

```
$('#toggle').click(function(e){
    // you may also want:
    // e.preventDefault();
    // depending what else you're doing, and how you're doing it
    $(this).val(function(i,v){ return v == 'Project Info +' ? 'Project Info -' : 'Project Info +'; });
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/ye8jK/).

Incidentally, if you're performing more than a single action on the same element/jQuery object, it would be wise to cache that object and subsequently use the cached object for future actions.

Bearing in mind I've used `click()` here, rather than `toggle()`, as the latter has been deprecated as of jQuery 1.9.

References:

- [`click()`](http://api.jquery.com/click/).
- [`toggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/).

Comment: It didn't work they way I wanted it, since the drop down page didn't show but the answer below combined yours with my code! and that fixed it! thanks again though!

Comment: If your problem is broader than your question implies, you should edit the question to include all the relevant code (but *only* the relevant code), HTML and JavaScript (and CSS if that's relevant to the particular problem). We may also benefit from a demo, in which case post a [Short, self-contained (SSCCE) example](http://sscce.org/) [JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/). Don't make us go to your site and sift through your code, make it *easy* for us; help us to help you. =)

Comment: Thanks for the anonymous function reminder; I often forget that part, nice solution with the ternary returned value. +1 for those

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$('#toggle').click(function() {
    $('#workinfo').slideToggle (300, 'linear');
    $(this).val( $(this).val() == 'Project Info +' ? 'Project Info -' : 'Project Info +'); 
});
```